# RMagick resizing image fails with "libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

We're using RMagick (version 2.13.2), along with carrierwave, carrierwave-mongoid, and Rails.

On our testing machine, when you upload an image to create an object, RMagick fails to resize the image.

The error in the log file is:

```
libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This doesn't happen on my development machine strangely enough.

This seems to be a common issue, such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091263/resizing-image-with-exec-and-convert-in-php/12100922#12100922).
I tried setting this environment variable, it didn't help.

Anyone has any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `convert` in my production server, which is a virtual server and has limited resources. I solved with the environment variable `MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1`

In ruby, you can solve this with

```
ENV['MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT']=1
```